# Decreasing "hunger" variable overtime

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, math

I'm trying to make a game something like don't starve where I have a variable called hunger. I want this to decrease overtime and if it goes to zero then the player's health starts decreasing as well. Also I would like it to deplate faster if you are sprinting (sprint is already working). The main question is simply how to decrease the hunger variable faster and faster overtime based on the last time you've eaten.

Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: You must have a variable to store the last thime you've eaten. Then can you start decrease the hunger using a function.

Comment: You can try power function `a*t^n` or exponential one `a*exp(b*t)`

Comment: Shouldn't hunger *increase* as time goes by?

Comment: @Rotem, if referring to aforementioned game the "fullness" was called "hunger". But I agree, it's confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant:
*Assuming your game got some kind of manager thread which monitors passing time and all global events are launched from there*

Figure out formula for derivative of that function  - it can be discrete. Store not only current value of "hunger" but alsotime stamp of last time of having food. Here, you can also have some kind of parameter, "food quality" that would affect speed? Difference between current time and timestamp gives you value to integrate your hunger decrease function by substracting result from "hunger".

Steps of check  might be irregular, then just derivative and passed time is not enough... e.g. if there was time skip because of sleeping (though such time skips might be emulated by increasing pace of  monitor thread). you have to store value of  time of last step was done.

Comment: Thanks, but what I don't really know is how to use time functions in unity (so how to make a function trigger after a time in the script) and yeah I know I need a mathematical function for this but I have no idea on how to find out one that i could use... Like I know a basic one (x^2) but I would like to make the slope a bit lower...

Comment: @user9578273 unity is just framework, not complete environment or language.. depends on what language you write on, what platform you use time and thread synchronization might be implemented differently. Also unity got awfully crude linear algebra which often needs tweaking\replacement. Works for most case except open-world games have issues with precision.